# How can I give my list icon a src in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want that my Icon get a src like `Icon: src='@/assets/icon'`

```
 items: [
  { icon: '', text: 'Sensor' },

  { icon: '', text: 'BarcodeScanner' }
]
```

But how do the syntax works?

Comment: items: [
      { icon: {src:'@/assets/Sensor'}, text: 'Sensor' },

      { icon: '', text: 'BarcodeScanner' }
    ] this do not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `require`, then they get loaded by webpack.

```
items: [
  { icon: require('@/assets/icons/WhatEver.png'), text: 'Sensor' }
]
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/32m5jj7141)

Comment: { icon: require('@/assets/Sensor.png'), text: 'Sensor' }, hmm thats seems not to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) `@` defined in your Webpack config?

Comment: It's working, I've added an example to my answer. Probably the is something wrong with your config.

Comment: yes you are right,, thx a lot <3